# Dishwasher Diagnosis

Tags: electrical, appliances, dishwasher

I have a Maytag Model mdbh949awb that stopped working without any indication that there was an issue. The cycle type (heavy, normal, light, rinse only) buttons on the left of the latch do not function but the heated dry, hi temp wash etc on the right are working. I checked the thermal fuse and door switches with my multimeter and they are passing a continuity test. When I looked at the ribbon from the LED's to the circuit board I noticed a small dark spot and I am wondering if that could be the issue, and if so, how I could test/fix it. I have attached pics of the cable and the door. I tried looking for a tech info booklet for this and I could not find it (i think the previous owner had the dw apart and lost it). I don't mind replacing the circuit board or the touch pad but I want to be certain of the dx before I spend the money. All LED's light up when I do the field test by pressing high temp wash + heated dry ~ 6x. Any assistance anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That spot looks superficial to me - it doesn't look like the conductor is damaged. You can test that by checking continuity on the ribbon cable. To get into the ribbon connector, if your multi-meter probes are too big, you may need a short piece of 22awg or so wire.

Comment: Unfortunately the other side of the ribbon is connected to to the LCD / Control Panel and is not removable.

Comment: Being connected on one side won't affect continuity testing (circuits work in a loop, and all the current from testing is only going over the ribbon cable). You just have to find a spot to stick your probe on (tip: sometimes it's easier to follow the trace and use the solder connection from the next component on the circuit board).

Comment: Had a duh moment.  That makes sense

Answer (score 1):

If this ribbon flexes , it is possible that it is broken. The LED's work that tells you that you at least have some parts of the cable working. The buttons are usually in a matrix - address and row. or a control signal and simply a row. You would be missing the control line in this case. So I would check the circuit board for a bad solder connection where that cable attaches. Checking continuity of the conductors on that cable - I would be flapping the cable a bit (while testing for continuity) to see if I lose continuity - looking for a cracked cable. Obviously this cable connects to a single touch pad. 
Simple solution to verify bad touch pad. Trace the wires that need to be connected for any one of these functions (heavy, normal, light, rinse only) then using a jumper wire JUMP them with the wire and see if the function lights up (remember you might need the door switch in the locked position).
If it does not try the same for the other non-working buttons and also one of the working buttons just to be sure. 
None of the functions work except the previously defined working function - then your controller is defective. 
If the functions all work then your keypad is defective.
Remember you are jumping them on that beautiful ribbon cable.